# Multi site sub sites redirect to root if www is NOT used in url

Tags: multisite

I have tested this on 2 different servers, new install of multisite and in both cases if www is not included in the url then you are redirected to the site root.

I tried a new install, no plugins and default theme:
targetremarket.com/test/site-template/  no www, installed in "test" sub folder.

That will redirect to 
http://www.targetremarket.com/test/  (site root)

I have an older install on same server that works fine so copied the htaccess from that but no luck.

Tried on another server, different domain, fresh wp install through cpanel and without www:
virtualgeorge.xyz/targetremarket/ (sub site)

redirects to:
http://www.virtualgeorge.xyz/  (also redirects to root)

I having some other strange behaviours which I assume is also due to this redirect issue.  How could I correct this, am I doing something wrong on setup?

Any tips much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this sorted. During setup using the installer for cpanel, I had to choose the option to install on my domain WITHOUT www. I was just leaving the default setting which used www and it was causing some issues.